# Database design: a many-to-one design where order matters

Tags: sql, sql-server, relational-database

I have two tables, **User** and **Game**. **Game** has columns `sideRed` and `sideBlue`. Each side has exactly one user. **User** has column `activeGame`. If `sideRed` and `sideBlue` are one-to-one relationships, then where does the back reference `activeGame` go?

Comment: It is not good design to store `side`s as columns. What if there will be `sideYellow`, `sideCyan` etc? +2 more columns? The better way is to use a dictionary of `side`s with `sideId`s, in `[game]` table keep `userid`, `sideid` and `isActive bit` column. In that way you don't need `activeGame` column in `[User]`s just join `[user]` and `[game]` on `userid` field and where `isactive=1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many users and many games. User should be connected to games somehow. This is typical *m:n-relationship*.

In your case this is restricted: Each game has exactly one user as `sideRed` and one user as `sideBlue`. At the moment your `game` table has two FK-columns to `user`-table to reference the blue and the red user. Correct so far?

Ask yourself some questions:

- Can a game connect to more than these two users (maybe later)?
- Can a user connect to several games (probably, as you are looking for a place to mark the active game)
- Is the user allowed to play more than one game (of the same type) actively (maybe later)?
- If you have several different games: Can a user take part in several different games at the same time? If yes: Are there several acitvely played different games where you'd need more than one `activeGame` flag?

You should always consider your ideas to grow :-)

You can put a fk-column into `user`-table to reference the active game. The problem: Your user must exist to fill the red and the blue column of the game row, but the game must exist to fill the activeGame column at the user. This cross reference needs special efforts on inserts...

You can set two `BIT` columns besides the `sideRed` and the `sideBlue` to mark this reference as the activeReference. In this case you'd have to make sure, that you do not allow more than one active flags per user.

### My suggestion (see update-section!)

Place a mapping table in between

- table game (just meta data to describe the game, no instance data)
- table user (just meta data to describe the user, no instance data)
- table UserGame (UserID, GameID, TypeID [red,blue,...] ...)
- table Session (the actively played game: UserGameID, loginTime, ...)

A wise man said: A good database is to be reckognized on the count of its tables. The more, the better :-)

Well, *the more the better* might not be a general rule, but - in most cases - one should not be afraid to invest a bit more in a good and scaleable structure

### UPDATE

Your comment

> I like this solution because it has strong separation of concerns.
>   Let's say Shnugo made a move, and we must broadcast to all users.
>   Shnugo's client sends a UserGameID and the requested move. Then you'd
>   1. Query for UserGame matching UserGameID. 2. Query Game matching GameID and apply move. 3. Query UserGames matching GameID and follow
>   the join to get a list of UserIDs in the game. Is this correct?

The game table in my design is just a meta-description of the game itself (Name, Icon, some rules ...). The **status of a specific game** (e.g. current positions of all chess figures) would need one (or several) more table(s), while the `UserGame`-table should hold a reference to this `GameStatus`-table **instead of a `GameID`**). You might need several different tables, as the status of Chess will need other structures than the status of Poker. But - looking into UserGame will tell you which game is played and so you know which table to look into.

### New suggestion

- table Game (just meta data to describe the game, no instance data)
- table User (just meta data to describe the user, no instance data)
- table GameInstance (status of currently played game, GameID,StatusID, ...)

  - game specific table(s) to store the game's current status
- table UserGame (UserID, **GameInstanceID**, TypeID [red,blue,...] ...)
- table Session (the actively played game: UserGameID, loginTime, ...)

Another possibility was to store all moves and calculate the current status. But this will not work for any kind of game.

Comment: YAGNI. I don't see how adding an extra layer of indirection helps. User has a join to UserGame, and UserGame has a join to Game. Same problem -- which column of Game does UserGame join to?

Comment: Ah, I get it. UserGame is many-to-one to Game, and Game just has a 'users' array. Which team the user is on is described in UserGame. Good work :)

Comment: You define the user (no discussion here I suppose) and the game (Poker is something else than chess). Then you have a table of running games: Jamie plays chess against Robert. Shnugo plays Poker against 5 other people. Oh, Jamie plays Poker as well.... Then there is one active session: Jamie plays chess at the moment and than switches to Poker to move something there and returns back to chess... See what I mean?

Comment: @Jamie, UserGame is m:n actually. One user may take part in several games at the same time and a game is played by several users...

Comment: I like this solution because it has strong separation of concerns. Let's say Shnugo made a move, and we must broadcast to all users. Shnugo's client sends a UserGameID and the requested move. Then you'd 1. Query for UserGame matching UserGameID. 2. Query Game matching GameID and apply move. 3. Query UserGames matching GameID and follow the join to get a list of UserIDs in the game. Is this correct?